# deleting marker after clicking the button - it deletes what is needed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox

I would like to delete the marker after clicking, I created a button in the popup, but after clicking this button, the popup itself is removed and the marker remains, can anyone help me solve this problem?

```
state = {
       newItems: [{Description: "opis...",  Name: "Pierwszy", X: 255,Y:100}],
}
  componentDidMount() {
 const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: this.mapContainer,
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
      center: [50, 100],
      zoom: 10,
    })

   for (const obj of newItems) {
      let myLatlng = new mapboxgl.LngLat(obj.X, obj.Y);
      new mapboxgl.Marker()
        .setLngLat(myLatlng)
        .setPopup(new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: 25 })
          .setHTML('<h3>' + obj.Name + '</h3><p>' + obj.Description + '</p><button onclick=(function(){event.target.parentNode.remove})();>Remove Marker</button>'
          ))
        .addTo(map);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<button>` which you are adding via [`Popup#setHTML`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#popup#sethtml) is a child of the [`Popup`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#popup) element itself, so clicking on the button and using `event.target.parentNode` will reference the `Popup` itself and not the [`Marker`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#marker). Although using [`Marker#setPopup`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#marker#setpopup) will link the popup with said marker, this method does not make the popup element a child of the marker element. This can be observed by checking, for example, the HTML of the page in this example after clicking on the marker to display the attached popup:

```
<div id="marker" class="mapboxgl-marker mapboxgl-marker-anchor-center" tabindex="0" ... ></div>

<div class="mapboxgl-popup mapboxgl-popup-anchor-bottom" ... > ... </div>
```

As you can see, the marker and popup are separate DOM nodes.

The implementation of `Marker#setPopup` in the source code [here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/blob/fb6d18d25ce19b2a7c03014fab2f74db25336acc/src/ui/marker.js#L326-L376) indicates that the method creates a reference to the relevant popup from the marker, but you can see in the implementation of popup.js [here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/blob/master/src/ui/popup.js) that popups do not reference a marker instance.

To achieve the effect you are looking for, you could create this bidirectional link between a marker and its popup by setting custom classes or IDs and then removing the marker with the relevant ID when its popup is clicked. You can use the optional `options.element` when initializing a `Marker` to create a unique ID attached to the marker's DOM element, and then use this same ID in conjunction with `Popup#setHTML` to reference the marker to be deleted when the button in the popup is clicked.